# How can I specify StrictHostKeyChecking=no while creating a Net::SSH:Expect object?

Tags: perl

Something like:

```
my %options = (
debug => 1,
options => ["ConnectTimeout 3","StrictHostKeyChecking no",],
);

# Making an ssh connection with user-password authentication
# 1) construct the object
    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (   
    host => $address,
        password=> 'password', 
    user => 'admin', 
    raw_pty => 1,
    log_stdout => 1
    );
```

the above does not seem to be working

Answer (score 4):

`StrictHostKeyChecking` is an option for the `ssh` program.

You can use the [Net::SSH::Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::SSH::Expect) option `ssh_option` in the constructor:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
    # ...
    ssh_option => '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
    # ...
);
```

Hat tip [salva](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188355/how-can-i-specify-stricthostkeycheckingno-while-creating-a-netsshexpect-objec/3188989#3188989).

Answer (score 1):

> StrictHostKeyChecking is an option for
>   the ssh  program. AFAIK, it cannot be
>   set on the command line for ssh

yes, it can!

Use...

```
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ...
```

Answer (score 0):

ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o ConnectTimeout=1